# How to get sc_module_name of the current running module

Tags: c++, systemc

When I create an instance if `sc_module` I give it a string as a module name (`sc_module_name`).

How can I get the name of the module that is currently running?

Answer (score 4):

To get the name of the module that is currently running in systemc:

Use `sc_get_current_process_b` to get the currently executing process (SC thread or method). Then use `get_parent` to get its parent, which is going to be the module. Then use `basename` or `name` to get its name:

```
const char* name = sc_core::sc_get_current_process_b()->get_parent()->basename();
```

(omitted error handling for brevity)

Comment: thanks thats what i needed.
BUT, is there any documentation on these functions?
for example if i have some OS threads running in parallel to some sc_threads, and an OS thread calls these functions what will happen?

Comment: I used [IEEE 1666](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf) and documentation in code (`systemc-2.2.0/src/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h`)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use name()

I used to use this to figure out which instance is doing what.

If that doesn't work it is because you need SC_HAS_PROCESS constructor instead of SC_CTOR

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the built-in macro for the constructor. Use the following, assuming that module name is "counter":

```
counter(sc_module_name _name):sc_module(_name)
{
    cout << "Creating object " << _name;
}
```

You can do various things with `_name` after you include `<string>`. You can use `string()`, concatenate with the `+` operator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is based on the reply in this [post](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/117-module-name/).*

You can simply use the method `name()` provided by `sc_object` (the base class of all sc_module) to get the hierarchical name of this module.

For example, I have a testbench `tb_adder` which contains an `Adder` as the submodule. Then in the `sc_main()` function (or anywhere you can access the module), I can use the `name()` method to get the name of each module.

The source code:

```
#include <systemc>
#include <iostream>


SC_MODULE(Adder) {
    sc_core::sc_in<bool>             clock;
    // more ports definition here

    void do_work() {
        /*do some work here */
    }

    SC_CTOR(Adder) {
        SC_CTHREAD(do_work, clock.pos());
    }
};

SC_MODULE(tb_adder) {
    sc_core::sc_in<bool> clock;

    Adder *dut;

    SC_CTOR(tb_adder) {
        dut = new Adder("adder");
        dut->clock(clock);
    }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    sc_core::sc_clock clock ("my_clock", 1, 0.5);

    tb_adder tb("tb_adder");
    tb.clock(clock);

    std::cout << "The name of the tb is: " << tb.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The name of the adder is: " << tb.dut->name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
The name of the tb is: cool_tb_adder
The name of the adder is: cool_tb_adder.fun_adder
```